# PKHUD and objective c errors

Tags: swift, objective-c

getting errors now when trying to do PKHUD commands in objective c

```
@import PKHUD;

[PKHUD sharedHUD].contentView = [[PKHUDProgressView alloc] initWithTitle:nil subtitle:@"UPDATING"];
[[PKHUD sharedHUD] hideAfterDelay:1 completion:NULL];
```

error like

> No visible @interface for 'PKHUDProgressView' declares the selector 'initWithTitle:subtitle:'

was working till I did a pod deintegrate and a pod install to fix another issue on a pod.

so this completely had me puzzled

Answer (score 1):

solved by adding this to the class mentioned in the error,

> @objcMembers

to the class PKHUDProgressView
becoming

```
@objcMembers open class PKHUDProgressView: PKHUDSquareBaseView, PKHUDAnimating {
```

most likely you need to so same for

> PKHUDProgressView

> PKHUDSuccessView

> PKHUDSuccessView

seems there is no tags for PKHUD on SO. hopefully google will catch this "PKHUD error"

last update to PKHUD was 5.3.0 2 years ago